# Where is the trained NER model saved after training the Spacy model with new Entities

Tags: python, model, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm still learning Python and creation of models and am very new to NLP using Spacy. I used https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner to train Spacy's existing model - en_core_web_sm.

I've trained this model with my domain specific entities.

```
def main(model="en_core_web_sm", new_model_name="new_ner_model", output_dir='/content/drive/My Drive/Data/new_model', n_iter=100):
.
.
(code to train the model)
.
.
    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.meta["name"] = new_model_name  # rename model
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)
```

Now I assumed that I would find a single model file within the output directory. Instead, what I have are 4 subfolders - *vocab, ner, tagger, parser*. And 2 files *meta.json and tokenizer*.
The *ner* subfolder has *cfg, moves, model*.

According to the website mentioned above, to load the new model, I need to use the entire folder (output directory), i.e.

`nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)`

Is the whole directory needed (is that the model) or is it the binary file named *model* within the *ner* subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we do advice to save the entire model as a folder, to make sure everything is loaded back in consistently. it won't work to just load the `model` file in by itself. It just contains the weights of the neural network. Some of the other files are needed to define the parameters and setup of your NLP pipeline & its different components. For instance, you always need the vocab data, etc.

One thing you could do, is disable the components you're not interested in. This will decrease the folder size on your disk and remove the redundant folders you don't want. For instance, if you're only interested in the NER, you could do:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "tagger"])`
```

Or, if you loaded the whole model, you could store just parts of it to disk:

```
nlp.to_disk(output_dir, exclude=["parser", "tagger"])
```

Comment: Thank you @sofie-vl. That really helped! It reduced the size to a 3rd of what it was.

Comment: Happy to hear it!